# Codeskulptor google chrome (unable to load files)

Tags: google-chrome

I click on a codeskulptor file link on chrome, it throws Unable to load file. What should I do, by the way, it works on Mozilla.

Answer (score 0):

It was resolved by disabling https everywhere extension.